# Change textview value in listview of android

Tags: android, listview

I want to increment the value in textview on button click event i hv written the code for the same but when i press +Button it increments the textview below it not on same textview.

there r two buttons + and -
on +button value should increment and
on -Button value should decremnt of textview in listview of android

here is my sample code ...
this my xml file

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/minus"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/minus"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/qty"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="+"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

and the code in adapter is below

```
 text5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 String qty=text4.getText().toString();
                 System.out.println("orginal string :"+qty);
                 int mn=Integer.parseInt(qty);
                 System.out.println("integer format : "+mn);
                 int  qty1=mn+1;
                 System.out.println("after increment :"+qty1); 
                 String s = new Integer(qty1).toString();
                 System.out.println("final string :"+s);
                 text4.setText(""+qty1);
                 App.qty=s;

            }
        });

     text6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 String qty=text4.getText().toString();
                 int mn=Integer.parseInt(qty);
                 int qty1=mn--;
                 text4.setText(""+qty1);
                 String s = new Integer(qty1).toString();
                 text4.setText(s);
                 App.qty=s;


            }
        });
```

Any help will be appreciated Thanks.

Comment: this is the code for incrementing and decrementing textview values.but you are not attaching these changed values to the listview

Comment: can u plz tell me waht is the error in above code Y?it is incrementing textview below it in listview ??

Comment: can you post the code for appending these textviews to listview

Comment: public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {// other code  
   text4 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.qty);
  
  text4.setText(video_path[position]);   /// other code}

Comment: so you are using adapter class right? then for every button click call adapter class and set textview values to corresponding textviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used arraylist instead of string array ..that sloved my problem